pandas.DataFrame advanced groupby clustering
Given the following dataframe (Python 3)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Smith', 'Brown', 'Smith', 'Miller'], 'Country': ['US', 'GB', 'DE','US']}, index=[0,1,2,3])
df.index.name = 'ID'
df

ID  Name    Country 
0   Smith   US
1   Brown   GB
2   Smith   DE
3   Miller  US

I want to perform "groupby" but where at least Name OR Country are identical. That is, ID0 is in the same cluster as ID2 due to sharing the same Name. However, ID0 shares the same Country as ID3, so they are both in the same cluster.
Hence the following groups or clusters should be found
{'cluster0':[0,2,3], 'cluster2':[1]}

Technically, we have an undirected graph where each individual "ID" is a node, and edges exist between nodes with identical names, as well as between nodes with identical Country.
How can we accomplish this in Pandas? Alternatively, would using the package networkx be better?

I don't believe that is possible.  The groupby operation uses a key to generate the groups.  The key can be a single value or a tuple of values, but the key must have a hash.  The issue is that you would need to create an object for the keys which meets the following requirements: hash(Key(('Smith', 'US'))) == hash(Key(('Smith', 'DE'))) and hash(Key(('Smith', 'US'))) == hash(Key(('Miller', 'US')))  Instead, you need to merge the data first as @ouroboros1 suggested to create the groups

You have to use a graph. Something like: df.index.groupby(df['Name'].map({n: i for i, c in enumerate(nx.connected_components(nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='Name', target='Country'))) for n in c}))

@mozway: Thanks, that works too! I also solved it in without networkx with df.groupby('Name).apply(lambda row: set(row.index)).to_list() + "same for Country". Then I double loop over the list of sets and merge them if they are not disjoint.

@PontusHultkrantz that's a risky approach, this will only work if you have a fixed level of overlapping.
